# Name property on class, use it for View Sample Data

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, binding, windows-phone-8

I make a class that has this property

```
public class PromoViewModel
{
   string name;
   // setter getter here...
   string description;
   // setter getter here...
   string img;
   // setter getter here...
}
```

The problem is, when I make a sample data like this

```
<vm:MainViewModel
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Dmall.ViewModels"
    SampleProperty="Sample Text Property Value">

    <vm:MainViewModel.Promos>
        <vm:PromoViewModel Name="design one" Description="Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" Img="Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur"/>
        <vm:PromoViewModel Name="design two" Description="Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" Img="Pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent"/>
        <vm:PromoViewModel Name="design three" Description="Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis" Img="Accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat"/>
    </vm:MainViewModel.Promos>

</vm:MainViewModel>
```

The error comes, because "Name" is special keyword for XAML, neither x:Name would work.
This result error on XAML Design Viewer because I try to do

```
{Binding Name}
// this would never exist because in the sample data, name is special attributes keyword not a property of PromoViewModel class and return NullReferenceException
```

I can easily change the name property in PromoViewModel Class to "Title" and it works.
But it's not efficient. How is the proper way to use property "Name" on a class and using it for sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `{Binding Path=Name}` so that you're explicitly setting the `Path` property.  Path is just the default property of a binding, so in this case you're ensuring that the binding knows that you're talking about `Path` and not `Name`.

The following works for me:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code-behind

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
vm.Name = "Test";

this.DataContext = vm;
```

Comment: There are no errors with the binding process.
The only error here is in the sample data file.
Name is special attribute keyword, and I can't use it for my name property.